# ruby, unexpected kend and end errors

Tags: ruby, rubygems, twitter

new to ruby, keep getting "kend and $end errors...Not too sure what i'm doing wrong.
Two options in this code, one should search for a user and return the tweet for each tweet which is a max of the given number. And other should search twitter tweets for a string and then return the result also.

```
require "rubygems"

require "twitter"

tweetsorlooks = String.new ARGV[1]

namesearchword = String.new ARGV[2]

number = String.new ARGV[3]



userurl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?           
include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=#{namesearchword }&count=#{number}'

searchurl = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#      
{namesearchword}&result_type=mixed'

statusresponse = RestClient.get(userurl)
userdata = statusresponse.body
userresult = JSON.parse(userdata)

queryresponse = RestClient.get(queryurl)
queryurl= queryresponse.body
queryresult= JSON.parse(queryurl)


if ARGV[1] == 'tweets'

puts

ref["userresult"].each do 

puts tweet["from_user"] + " : " + tweet["text"]

end

else 

puts

ref["queryresul"].each do 

puts tweet["from_user"] + " : " + tweet["text"]

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get used to indent your code properly:

```
if ARGV[1] == 'tweets'
  puts
  ref["userresult"].each do 
    puts tweet["from_user"] + " : " + tweet["text"]
  end
else 
  puts
  ref["queryresul"].each do 
    puts tweet["from_user"] + " : " + tweet["text"]
  end
```

now the problem is obvious.

Comment: `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- twitter (LoadError)

Comment: the gem cannot be found. First thing to try is `gem install twitter`. Are you using software like Rvm or Rbenv?

Comment: @JörgWMittag true. If someone is searching for one, i use Vim where you only have to type `gg=G` and everything will be indented for you.

Comment: not using any software, just some work for a project...ill try the install twitter..other than tghe indent code issue, does my code look fine, should it work? New to Ruby...

Comment: ok, new errors now..Fark! Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_BOUNDARY
./filename.rb:6:in `initialize': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
 from ./filename.rb:6:in `new'
 from ./filename.rb:6

Comment: seems something to do with arguments and new. string

Comment: any ideas? apprecciate the help.!

Comment: `ARGV[2]` is `nil` and thus "empty". Drop the `String.new` completely. You also probably want `ARGV[0]` and `1` instead of `1` and `2`. Computer scientists start to count at zero ;)

Answer (score 3):

An `end` is missing in the end. The outer `if` loop is not properly closed.

Comment: `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- twitter (LoadError) ??